# UIsegmented control not working inside collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol

Hi I am trying to trigger events for UIsegment control inside the collection view.

here is my code.

```
CollectionViewCell.h

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *mySegmentedControl;

ViewController.m
{  
NSInteger selectedSegment;
}

- (UIView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
cell.mySegmentedControl.tag = indexPath.row;
selectedSegment = cell.mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
 [cell.mySegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 }

- (void) segmentValueChanged: (UISwitch *) sender {
//NSInteger index = sender.tag;
if(selectedSegment == 0)
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"!Alert"
                                                message:@"Do you think this property is not exists?"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
[alert show];

}         
else
{
    //your code
}
}
```

The above code not works for me.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the complete code for `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. You should read the `selectedSegmentIndex` in `segmentValueChanged:` into a local variable.

Comment: @Raj - have you tried with setting breakpoint inside - (void) segmentValueChanged:(UISwitch *) sender .It will call only when you tapped on segmented control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is not `UISwitch` it is `UISegmentedControl` do like

```
- (void) segmentValueChanged: (UISegmentedControl *) sender {
//NSInteger index = sender.tag;
if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"!Alert"
                                                message:@"Do you think this property is not exists?"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
[alert show];

}         
else
{
    //your code
}
}
```

Comment: use UIAlertController , UIALertView is deprecated